# How to clear the SharedPreferences for a particular key?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app and I am using shared prefs.

I am setting shared prefs, I am using one key called ALL_DONE_VIEW but the case is that I am attaching one unique id for ex:  "123 + ALL_DONE_VIEW",
"234 + ALL_DONE_VIEW" etc.

Now on logout, I want to clear all the shared prefs of "ALL_DONE_VIEW" key.

Can we do that using only "ALL_DONE_VIEW" key without unique id? or do I need to use unique id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all keys and iterate through them using a `for` loop to check if a key contains a certain pattern, then remove it.

**Java**

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

  for (String key : preferences.getAll().keySet()) {
      if (key.contains("ALL_DONE_VIEW")) {
          editor.remove(key);
      }
}

 editor.apply();
```

**Kotlin**

```
val prefernces = getSharedPreference("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = preferences.edit()

for (key in preferences.all.keys) {
    if (key.contains("ALL_DONE_VIEW")
        editor.remove(key)
}

 editor.apply()
```

Answer (score 1):

create different shared preference with the name `ALL_DONE_VIEW`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ALL_DONE_VIEW, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("123 + ALL_DONE_VIEW", "value");
editor.putInt("456 + ALL_DONE_VIEW", 123);
...
editor.apply();
```

than for removing remove editor itself using this line

```
editor.clear().apply()
```

NOTE: don't forget to call `apply()` after editing prefs

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of SharedPreferences.Editor, remove method:

```
   /**
     * Mark in the editor that a preference value should be removed, which
     * will be done in the actual preferences once {@link #commit} is
     * called.
     * 
     * <p>Note that when committing back to the preferences, all removals
     * are done first, regardless of whether you called remove before
     * or after put methods on this editor.
     * 
     * @param key The name of the preference to remove.
     * 
     * @return Returns a reference to the same Editor object, so you can
     * chain put calls together.
     */
    Editor remove(String key);
```

Comment: yes, but for that, I also need to pass a unique id. I want to achieve this without passing unique id

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove one record/saved datum in SharedPreferences.

```
getSharedPreferences("NAME", 0).edit().remove(Unique id + "ALL_DONE_VIEW").apply();
```

If you want "ALL_DONE_VIEW" to be constant, just pass the unique id in this way.

And Priyankagb's answer is acceptable and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the key whichever contains your "ALL_DONE_VIEW", you remove it

```
Map<String, ?> map = sharedPreferences.getAll();
```

You can use this to get a map for all the sharedPreferences pair... then do filtering then delete whichever pairs you want

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
 SharedPreferences s = mContext.getSharedPreferences("", 1);
    Iterator<String> keyList = s.getAll().keySet().iterator();
    do {
        if (keyList.hasNext()) {
            String key = keyList.next();
            if (key.contains("ALL_DONE_VIEW")) {
                s.edit().remove(key);
            }
        }
    } while (keyList.hasNext());
```

its just a rough idea you can change it to your way.
Iterate on all the keys in the preferences and remove the corresponding key which contains the prefix of your key.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void Logout() { 
  SharedPreferences prefs = MyApplication.context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefConstants.APP_PREFERENCE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.clear();
  editor.apply(); 
}
```